# Yehi Ratzon After Birkas Kohanim

Tags: halacha, tefilla, birchas-kohanim

Is there reason to say the Yehi Ratzon in Birkas Kohani after the third stanza (ending in 'shalom')? I always said it quietly based on the Artscroll Machzor but have have been uncertain due to the [Mishna Berura (130:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.130.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.130.5&lang2=bi) writing

> בסוף כל פסוק שמסיימין והם ג' פעמים [א"ר] וכן כתוב בשם הגר"א שהיה נוהג
>   לומר גם בסוף פסוק ג' הרבש"ע הנ"ל שהוזכר בגמרא ולא היה"ר הנדפס  בסידורים - After each stanza say the Ribono Shel Olam. The Gra would do the same after the third stanza, not saying the Yehi Ratzon printed in Siddurim.

Comment: [The translation is imprecise]

Answer (score 1):

In his siddur Rav Yaacov Emden brings the source to say it from the kisvey haari. He then includes a paragraph where the Ari connects the time of nisiyas kapayim, when the cohanim's hands are outstretched, as a time of shefah (a blessing of plenty) from Hashem so it appears to be a very special time to ask for things from Hashem, and presumably, hence the content of the "yehee ratzon" tefilah which is basically asking Hashem for many things.